# Is the olive oil I get for my menorah regular regular olive oil?

Tags: menora-chanukia, candle-lighting, oil

Some are accustomed to light for Shabbos, Yom Tov, and Chanukah with olive oil. Is this olive oil (such as the one sold at my local judaica store [here](http://israelbookshop.com/judaica-books/Menorahs/Oil-2.html)) the same type that one can get in a grocery store, or is it specially prepared to burn in a different way?

Comment: A quick look at the Wiki page for olive oil indicates that it's 100 percent fat.  It should all burn quite nicely.  The listing they have of the grades/types indicates that even the "lampante" oil that isn't fit for human consumption can still be used for burning. The different "quality" grades are based on how nice it should taste, not how well they burn.

Comment: Is this on topic @DoubleAA?

Comment: @mevaqesh, following from here [http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic], it appears to fall under the category of "general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Judaism"

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt well the link didn't work. However, this seems to neither be a question about Judaism, nor about an auxiliary discipline which would facilitate the practice of Judaism. It is equivalent to asking which species of mold tends to grow on one's _dalet minnim_. That is, I fail to see how, by any definition, this relates directly to Judaism.

Comment: @mevaqesh, this question is a practical question about the similarity of various types of olive oil, as, if they burn similarly, it seems somewhat silly to buy the more expensive, leichter brand, oil, when I can get perfectly good, less expensive oil (hechshered even!) at my grocery to light with. If you think that this question works better at a sci.SE type site, then that is a separate issue, but as this relates to oil for use in lighting for Shabbos, yontif, and Chanukah, it seems on-topic to me. Also, remove the final bracket in the link and it should work.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Well consider clarifying why a question is relevant; such as its combustion characteristics, in the question.

Comment: @mevaqesh It is relevant in the fact that some Poskim hold Lechatchillah one should use olive oil that is Rauy Le'achillah so some specifically buy regular olive oil. However, I heard in a Shiur that Chanukah olive oil is Rauy Le'achillah, just its a lower grade. I can't remember who I heard that from.

Comment: But unquestionably regular olive oil is just as Mehudar, if not more Mehudar.

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66046/edible-oil-for-menorah?rq=1 for more on this topic.

Comment: @Eliyahu, if Chanukah oil is a lower grade, why does it cost more than extra virgin olive oil at my local grocer?

Comment: @Eliyahu Again, any reasons for relevance should be edited into the question itself.

Comment: I don't know. Its cheaper by my local grocer. My guess is that someone (either the supplier or the grocery) realizes that people think that its preferable and will be willing to pay more for it, which is questionable Assur as Onaah.

Comment: I think the Talmud in Shabbat (pretty sure it's in 2nd chapter) discusses the list of permissible Chanukah lighting oils. It's quite extensive. At any rate, I'm not sure why places charge so much higher for menorah olive oil when any kosher olive oil may be used. FYI, IIRC, OU among a few others state that 100% extra virgin olive oil needs no certification symbol. So, seems that you can use San Giussepe or Berrio, etc. and save a good deal of money. And you'll have left-over for your salad.

Comment: @DanF, I believe you are right that the OU holds that way (IIRC, that also applies to Pesach)

Answer (score 1):

Olive oil sold in the stores will work fine (or even better than) the Judaica store oils. Some of the Judaica oils are really low quality even though they charge more for it on average.

I've used both and never noticed much of a difference in burning quality.

Comment: The fancy label costs a lot, ya know... ;)